# How to download a single directory from a Git repository

Tags: git, github

What is the shortest, simplest way (preferably one line command) to download a single subdirectory from a Git repository? The goal is for an *end-user* (i.e. not a programmer) to get a copy of a subdirectory as easily as possible.

---

This is related to, but not a clone of "[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)", as that question concerns itself with cloning the directory and still being able to use the directory within Git. Whereas I just want the user to get a local copy, git history, and other information need not be downloaded in my case. Its ok if it is, its just not required.

Comment: Do you really mean github in particular, as opposed to git in general?

Comment: I'm using github, so a github answer would be helpful, but I presume there are few differences between a github repo and a regular git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Note that git, intrinsically, has nothing to do with downloads. A git repo just sits there on your disk, except for [git daemon](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon), which does will not help you make downloads available to ordinary users.

As far as I know, there is no *easy* way to do what you want. github in particular supports various ways to download flat files, but I do not believe that it provides a URL that packages up a directory; all it can do is 'release' tarballs. Subdirectories are especially problematic: you need a web service that responds with a ZIP or tar file, and the user will have to interact with the browser to get it unpacked.

I did find [a PHP solution](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/tutorial-create-a-zip-file-from-folders-on-the-fly/) that you could layer atop a file system that happened to be populated from a git repo.

Answer (score 0):

If the subdirectory was a submodule, it would be relatively easy; just `git clone` that. But you'd still get the whole repo, not the working tree. If you want *just the working tree* there is nothing *git* can do for you.

So you'd have to do things differently.If it is on a machine that you have control over you could make the directory in question accessible via e.g;

- rcp
- rsync
- ftp (as a zip or tar file)